# Reading and writing integers to a binary file using C?

Tags: c, file-io, binary-data

I am trying to write 100 integers to binary file. I have tried writing to this file, and reading from it. When reading from it I get completely random digits.

Here is the block concerning the write.

Do note I have the file open for write with "wb" mode. I have also closed the file at the end.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
}
```

Here is the block concerning the read.
Do note I do have the file open here in "rb" mode and it is closed.

```
    int num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int rc = getc(file);
        if (rc == EOF) {
            fputs("Error occured while reading file", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    printf("%d", num);
}
```

My output is like this:

```
-13421772802147469895-168955699232767012640583688388440-104919389914260634872147467638000128293273683884400-19797114882147440795-168947558432767-1097029212883066888388440148657280313254001912147440795-168942592032767-109702911303445504838844014865730434362077432147440795-168935577632767-1097029063753420883766251486573257-6039796492147440795-168932864032767-109702901326841856838844014865733541270-168949760032767-10970289133241241683884401486573450-1090518913214744079500196944831217016018891752457584192041348617175279241952408940298110176910929517683167731702125413116313304413809989891296126535181930809719192433591818324585127960891517680423011935761967-13421772802147469895-168955699232767012640583688388440-104919389914260634872147467638000128293273683884400-19797114882147440795-168947558432767
```

So there is something wrong, and I am not sure what exactly. Perhaps I am not sure if I understand the API for reading/writing completely (specifically size_t nitems)? I am not sure how to tell how many bytes I need to read/write from a file.

Comment: this line: `fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 100, file);` is wrong, what it should be is: `fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);`

Comment: Can we assume that the 'read' block is the body of a loop that iterates 100 times?

Comment: Yes, that is a correct assumption. Sorry. And I have made the change to fwrite to be 1, but it is still the same problem.

Comment: The posted question is missing one of the key criteria of stack overflow.  I.E. a complete, short, cleanly compiles code that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Please post MCVE. There are most likelly more problems in your code, other than buffer size.

Comment: Agreed - I have updated the code in the original statement.

Comment: Huh. That fixed it. But how did it know it reached EOF? Or better yet how do I ensure the file isn't blank before I read it?

Comment: `fread` will return zero when it can't read any further. Remember to end gracefully after that as it's not an error.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Btw. you only write 99 values into the file and then expect to find 100 in it, so it probably *is* an error if it can't read any further, after all.

Comment: Yeah I just fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first loop, you are writing 100 integers starting at the address of 'i', 99 times.

Not what I think you were thinking you were doing.

it should be

```
fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

Secondly, what mode do you open the file for writing? It should be opened in binary mode otherwise it will not save binary data correctly (add 'b' to the fopen mode value)

DO you close and reopen the file for the read (and set the right file mode?) or if I was left open, do you fseek back to beginning of the file before trying to read the values.

Comment: I have fixed that just now. It did not change anything. I suspect there could be something wrong with my read, in which case I will update the original post with additional code.

Just to clarify, the file is open/closed correctly and defined with "rb" and "wb" params respectively.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. I suspect it has something to do with getc().

Comment: Yes, the `getc` consumes one character that was a part of your int, and then you are reading a different (misaligned) variable. If you print a new line after `%d` you'll see that sometimes it "catches up" but at a wrong rate. Drop the `getc` and find some other means of detecting an EOF.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: whats the getc even needed for?

Comment: use feof() to detect end of file. Currently the read code is probally not even correct - its reading 100 character and then a single int?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really sure what I was trying to do. I was trying to make sure the file wasn't blank to begin with and trying to stop the loop if I hit end of the file *before* the for loop is over. I guess I could have used a while-loop and kept reading until freads == null, and just kept track of my own index.